# DDoS false IP attack

Tags: ddos, spoofing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DDoS attack, how to stop?](https://serverfault.com/questions/97476/ddos-attack-how-to-stop)

I'm getting 10MB attacks, IP spoofing, which is used fake IPs, causing high CPU usage of the machine, and falls all. What should I do to prevent it?
Dedicated server configuration:
Dual Core 2.8
2GB RAM
Uplink 1Gbps
Centos.
Hug!

Comment: Figure out what it is about the attack that's allow that traffic rate to cause high CPU usage and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Contact your ISP and ask them to drop it before it reaches you.

Comment: I've talked with them, they only prevent attacks over 1Gbps

Comment: I use securedservers.com

Comment: But how do I protect myself against it within the server?

Comment: You can't.  It's already saturated your link. IPTables to drop/reject the traffic might help, but you'll still be receiving the traffic, so even IPTables will have to use CPU to process the traffic.

Comment: And a dedicated server, with Quad-Core 2.4 and 8GB of RAM, solve?

Comment: It won't scale like that.  The only cure for a DDOS is your ISP's participation.

Comment: Like  Tom says, there is no other way.